# Transition maps for holomorphic vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, complex-manifolds

In the definition of a holomorphic line bundle of rank $n$, it is required that the transition maps $g_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\to\text{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ are holomorphic.

What does this actually mean? Are we seeing $\text{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ as a complex manifold? Otherwise I can't even make sense of this being continuous? Is it a problem that these may have highly different dimensions?

I am mainly thinking about Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Yes, $GL_n(\Bbb C) \subseteq \Bbb C^{n^2}$ is seen as a complex manifold(it is an open subset). The condition that transition maps should be holomorphic follows from the trivialisations $g_i : \pi^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i $ which are holomorphic. Then $g_{ij}=g_i \circ g_j^{-1}$ is holomorphic. This could also be seen as necessary when constructing the bundle from transition maps.